# How to bulk delete the entities in datastore of GCP when bulk delete template of dataflow is deprecated?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-dataflow, gql

How can we do bulk delete entities in datastore now especially when Bulk Delete Entities in Datastore  template is deprecated in dataflow of Google cloud...

Is there any other way...

Answer (score 0):

[As mentioned in the docs](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-utilities#:%7E:text=Please%20migrate%20to%20Firestore%20Bulk%20Delete%20template.), you can continue to use the dataflow templates to bulk delete entities.

The rename is to simply clarify that the template works for both Cloud Datastore & Cloud Firestore in Datastore mode.